# external dict in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use external dictionary with somehow "mapped" variables:

```
one_changes:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

In my playbook I'm using vars_files which is recognized. Now, how do I do something like this:

```
name: variables_one
  replace:
    dest=/one/file.php
    regexp="{{ one_changes.key }}"
    replace="{{ one_changes.value }}"
  with_items:
    - one_changes
```

I cannot for sake of god figure it out since few hours. There are many variables for many files so I'd like to keep them mapped separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [chapter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes) about this in documentation.

First, mind the indentation in your yaml file:

```
one_changes:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

Second, use `with_dict`:

```
- name: variables_one
  replace:
    dest: /one/file.php
    regexp: "{{ item.key }}"
    replace: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ one_changes }}"
```

Comment: It still gives me "The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'key'". The indentation is ok, I just copied it wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. It's item.key and item.value instead of dict's name. Thank you.

Comment: What if I want to loop through few subfolders now? Instead of /one/file.php I'd like to loop through one1 and one2 more, with the same file.

Comment: Fixed variable name. To make nested loop there is `with_nested`, but it works only with lists, so you will need to refactor your `one_changes` into list of dicts to work correctly.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this